# How do I sample audio for real-time processing?

Tags: python, audio, sampling

Audio is a complex sine wave. I want to sample data from an audio file playing and manipulate it.

Each sample should be a list of the amplitudes of the sine wave at a number of intervals.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to read a wav file, the wave library should do this fine:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html

For example:

```
import wave
CHUNK_SIZE=1024
wf = wave.open('filename.wav')
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK_SIZE)
while data != '':
    do_something(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK_SIZE)
```

Will read 1024 samples into data. That is, data will be an array of 1024 entries, each the amplitude at a particularly time, where that time is dependent on the framerate of the file. See this question: [What does a audio frame contain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957025/what-does-a-audio-frame-contain) for more explanation.

Comment: I tried this. Each chunk is a bunch of hex (\xff for example). Is there a way to convert all of these to integers?

Comment: int(hexstring.encode('hex'),16) will convert a string like '\xff' to decimal

Comment: These questions cleared it up for me:
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963699/how-do-i-fix-this-error-typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface/14963750#14963750[/link]
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961562/how-do-i-convert-a-string-of-hexadecimal-values-to-a-list-of-integers[/link]