# How do I convert a string of hexadecimal values to a list of integers?

Tags: python, audio, hex, signal-processing, waveform

I have a long string of hexadecimal values that all looks similar to this:

```
'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00'
```

The actual string is 1024 frames of a waveform. I want to convert these hexadecimal values to a list of integer values, such as:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0]
```

How do I convert these hex values to ints?

Comment: You have a byte string, which python, when printing, converts to a string literal representation for you. The `\x00` escapes are used for any byte that is not a printable ASCII character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) in combination with [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> s = '\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00'
>>> map(ord, s)
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Not the best way of doing it, not with `struct.unpack()` available and capable of interpreting bytes as other types too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- But a clever way to do it for this very limited problem ... It made me smile.

Comment: This solution is 6 times slower than `struct.unpack`, btw.. `struct` takes 0.3 seconds for a million iterations, while `map(ord, s)` needs 1.8 seconds.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If we were looking for high performance in waveform processing, we would probably choose something other than Python anyway.

Comment: @cdhowie: Perhaps. Still, no need to use something that is so much slower at the same operation. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Perhaps. If the input is only going to be 1,024 bytes each time then the difference is likely to be negligible. My only points against `struct.unpack()` are (1) an extra import, and (2) you have to do some string formatting with `len()` to get the length of the string into the format specifier, which strikes me as a bit unwieldy. Of course you can hide that behind a function, but I prefer to take the clean solution and optimize later, after profiling.

Comment: @cdhowie: with 1024 bytes each time `map()` is 10 times slower, actually. `array.array()` becomes the fastest option, in that case, beating out `struct.unpack()` by about 20%.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Relatively, sure.. but how much CPU time would it take relative to everything else happening in the script? Again, code and *then* optimize.

Comment: @cdhowie: But knowing *beforehand* what will be faster wins you half the battle. Stack Overflow gives you the opportunity to be aware of the options you have for a given operation; by adding timing information to the answers here you can make a more informed choice *without* having to go and optimize this yourself should the need for optimization arise.

Comment: It's great to know faster ways to solve problems. In this case, however, my code doesn't need to be quick. I would argue that more people know about `map` and `ord` than `struct.unpack`, which makes my code more readable to the average programmer.

Comment: I have a question: How do you achieve the opposite the opposite? That is fom a list [0, 1, 2, ...] get a string "\x00\x01\x02..." ? Is there a function for this?

Comment: @Apostolos `str.join('', (chr(i) for i in your_list))`

Comment: Thanks, but this gives garbage, I mean the string contains control chars, etc. BTW, this can be coded more simply as `"".join((chr(i) for i in lst))`. Now, what I asked was if there is a function for converting a list to a string like "\x01\x02\x03...". I can do this of course "manually" with `"".join("\\x%02x" % (i) for i in lst)`, but this is a whole operation (even in compact form), not a function.

Comment: @Apostolos That's not the same string. What do you think \x01 means in a string literal?

Comment: Why don't you JUST try it?  `print "\x01"` prints a happy face!  (Not mine at this moment :))   To obtain "x\01" as such, you have to use `print r'"\x01"`.

Comment: @Apostolos Correct, but that's not what OP means.  By `\x01` the OP _means_ the single control character, not the sequence of four characters `\x01`. If you want the actual escape notation (for some strange reason), `repr()` is a thing.

Comment: ... Lost in translation - OK, Let's not waste the space of this thread anymore.

Answer (score 9):

use [`struct.unpack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

```
>>> import struct
>>> s = '\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00'
>>> struct.unpack('11B',s)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0)
```

This gives you a `tuple` instead of a `list`, but I trust you can convert it if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [11]: a
Out[11]: '\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00'

In [12]: import array

In [13]: array.array('B', a)
Out[13]: array('B', [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0])
```

Some timings;

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'text = "\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00";' ' map(ord, text)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.775 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s 'import array;text = "\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00"' 'array.array("B", text)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.29 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s 'import struct; text = "\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00"'  'struct.unpack("11B",text)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.165 usec per loop
```

Comment: Not bad; 0.665 seconds for a million iterations. `struct` is still faster, but you can manipulate an `array` and get a byte representation back with fewer steps.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - praise from the master! Guido can't be wrong  [optimization anectode](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/)