# Converting string which contains bytearray to uint16

Tags: python, arrays, data-conversion

I have a large bytearray which I store to a file, for post-processing purposes. For this example, let's assume the data is a counter from 0 to 3 base 10.

The format I retrieve the data in from a certain method is a bytearray, and I need to store it efficiently as the simulation requires a large data-set. Therefore I store it as

```
f=open('data_0.txt','w')
f.write(str(b_a))
f.close()
```

when I read it I get a string of data: `data_read =  b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00'`

```
f=open('data_0.txt')
data_read = f.read()
f.close()
```

I expect a function to take the string: `b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00'` and convert it to an array of `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

When I use `struct.unpack("BBBBBBBB" , data_read)` I would expect `0,0,1,0,2,0,3,0`, instead it just displays the ascii for b,',\,x, etc., it is the same for `ord(0)`, `ord(1)` etc.

Is there any convenient function or pythonic manner to go from a string:  `b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00'` and convert it to an array of `[0, 1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961562/how-do-i-convert-a-string-of-hexadecimal-values-to-a-list-of-integers this helps you maybe. ord and map

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `short`s or `unsigned short`s:)

```
>>> import struct
>>> data_read
b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00'
>>> struct.unpack("hhhh" , data_read)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
>>> struct.unpack("HHHH" , data_read)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Hello, I'm not familiar with `struct` yet, do you use four H because you expect a four-values array?

Comment: The `data_read` is 8 `bytes` in length. And since you are expecting 4 values, i used `unisgned short`s

Answer (score 0):

If you get the ascii display for b,',\,x, etc., it means that the file actually contains it. In fact it is caused by the `str(b_a)` call.

Demo:

```
>>> b_a = b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00'
>>> s_a = str(b_a)
>>> print(s_a)
b'\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00'
>>> [hex(ord(x)) for x in s_a]
['0x62', '0x27', '0x5c', '0x78', '0x30', '0x30', '0x5c', '0x78', '0x30', '0x30', '0x5c', '0x78', '0x30', '0x31', '0x5c', '0x78', '0x30', '0x30', '0x5c', '0x78', '0x30', '0x32', '0x5c', '0x78', '0x30', '0x30', '0x5c', '0x78', '0x30', '0x33', '0x5c', '0x78', '0x30', '0x30', '0x27']
```

which is the display for b, ', \, x, 0, etc.

`ast.literal_eval` can be used to convert it back to a byte string. Demo:

```
>>> b2 = ast.literal_eval(s_a)
>>> b2 == b_a
True
>>> struct.unpack('HHHH', b2)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

So if you want to keep the `str` call when writing, you have to read it that way:

```
with open('data_0.txt') as f:
    data_read = f.read()
data = struct.unpack('HHHH', ast.literal_eval(data_read))
```