# How do I fix this error? TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, string, runtime-error

```
>>> import struct
>>> s = '\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00'
>>> struct.unpack('11B', s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    struct.unpack('11B', s)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

What is wrong with this? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On python 3, `struct.unpack()` expects an object that implements the buffer protocol, such as a [`bytes`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) value, not a [unicode `str`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str):

```
>>> import struct
>>> s = b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00'
>>> struct.unpack('11B', s)
(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0)
```

If you are reading this data from a file, open the file in binary mode instead of text mode to get bytes.